# prove $f(x)f(y)=f(xy), f(1)=1 \iff f(x)=x^k (k\ real)$

Tags: calculus, functional-equations

> prove $f(x)f(y)=f(xy), f(1)=1 \iff f(x)=x^k (k\ real)$ for $f:\mathbb{R}^+\to \mathbb{R}^+$

I find $f(a^r)=f(a)^r$ for rational r, but I cannot move to the next step.

Comment: Do we additionally assume that $f$ is continuous? Otherwise the statement seems false to me. If you have continuity, then you can use a density argument.

Comment: If $g(x)$ is a discontinuous solution to [Cauchy's Functional Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation) then $f(x)=e^{g(\ln x)}$ satisfies your functional equation.